# Multiple Async File Uploads with chunking to ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have read a number of closely related questions but not one that hits this exactly. If it is a duplicate, please send me a link.

I am using an angular version of the flowjs library for doing HTML5 file uploads (https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow). This works very well and I am able to upload multiple files simultaneously in 1MB chunks.  There is an ASP.Net Web API Files controller that accepts these and saves them on disk. Although I can make this work, I am not doing it efficiently and would like to know a better approach.

First, I used the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider in an async method that worked great as long as the file uploaded in a single chunk.  Then I switched to just using the FileStream to write the file to disk. This also worked as long as the chunks arrived in order, but of course, I cannot rely on that.

Next, just to see it work, I wrote the chunks to individual file streams and combined them after the fact, hence the inefficiency. A 1GB file would generate a thousand chunks that needed to be read and rewritten after the upload was complete.  I could hold all file chunks in memory and flush them after they are all uploaded, but I'm afraid the server would blow up.

It seems that there should be a nice asynchronous solution to this dilemma but I don't know what it is. One possibility might be to use `async`/`await` to combine previous chunks while writing the current chunk. Another might be to use `Begin`/`EndInvoke` to create a separate thread so that the file manipulation on disk was handled independent of the thread reading from the `HttpContext` but this would rely on the `ThreadPool` and I'm afraid that the created threads will be unduly terminated when my MVC controller returns. I could create a `FileWatcher` that ran completely independent of ASP.Net but that would be very kludgey.

So my questions are, 1) is there a simple solution already that I am missing? (seems like there should be) and 2) if not, what is the best approach to solving this inside the Web API framework?

Thanks, bob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that kind of chunked upload, but I believe this should work:

- Use `flowTotalSize` to [pre-allocate the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when the first chunk comes in.
- Have one `SemaphoreSlim` per file to serialize the asynchronous writes for that file.
- Each chunk will [write to its own offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`flowChunkSize * (flowChunkNumber - 1)`) within the file.

This doesn't handle situations where the uploads are unexpectedly terminated. That kind of solution usually involves allocating/writing a temporary file (with a special extension) and then moving/renaming that file once the last chunk arrives.

Don't forget to [ensure that your file writing is actually asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.isasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That sounds perfect! I didn't know that could be done. Hopefully, I can get back to this code this afternoon and try this out. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but it appears that you cannot write chunks out of order without throwing an exception. Jon Skeet says as much in this question http://tinyurl.com/kelqk9k.

Comment: It's not possible to *insert*. What I'm suggesting is *overwrite*. It should work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to come back and mark this as a correct answer. It worked great when I implemented correctly.

Comment: @Bob - Trying to do the same thing here. Is your successful solution available publicly? Could use some sample code to help me get started.

Answer (score 7):

Using @Stephen Cleary's answer, and this thread: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/issues/41 I was able to make an ASP.NET Web Api Implementation and uploaded it for those still wondering about this question such as @Herb Caudill

https://github.com/samhowes/NgFlowSample/tree/master.

The original answer is the real answer to this question, but I don't have enough reputation yet to comment. I did not use a SemaphoreSlim, but instead enabled file Write sharing. But did in fact pre-allocate and make sure that each chunk is getting written to the right location by calculating an offset.

I will be contributing this to the Flow samples at: https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/tree/master/samples

Comment: FWIW, "I don't have enough reputation yet" isn't a valid reason. Link only answers are also discouraged. But thanks for helping; our rules take a while to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done. Uploaded the chunks and saved those chunks on the server an save the location of chunks in the database with their order (not the order they came in, the order of the chunk in the file they should be).

Then I introduced another endpoint to merge those chunks. Since this part can be a long process I used a messaging service to run the process in the background.

And after the service is done merging the file, sending a notification (or you can trigger an event).

Agree, it won't fix the problem of having to save all those chunks, but after the merging is done, we can just delete those from the disk. However there are some IIS configuration required though for the upload to work smoothly.

Here's my two cents to this old question. Now most of the application use azure or aws for storage. However, still sharing my thoughts in case it helps someone.